# Why my output result doesnt show 0 when it's supposed to show exact number in reverse order in Python.Without changing parameter variable to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why my output result doesn't show 0  when it's supposed to show exact  number in reverse order in Python.Without changing the parameter variable to string.

```py
parameter = int(input())
sum = 0
while parameter > 0:
    digit = parameter % 10
    sum = sum * 10 + digit
    parameter = parameter // 10
print(sum)
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to do `input()[::-1]`?

Comment: I mean for e.g while i type 420 it shows only 24 not 024

Comment: You aren't dealing with digits; you are only printing the number defined *using* the digits. `sum` has no idea if there were 1, 2, or 100 leading 0s in the reversal of the given input.

Comment: Isn't `24` and `024` the same number? Are you trying to print a number or print a string?

Comment: Well it's said that I cant use string for this

Comment: Just print each digit directly. There is no benefit from building a sum when you don't actually want a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are going on here. First, you're converting the input to an `int`. This means that when reversing the number you'll lose all trailing 0s. This is because for an int there is no reason to show a leading 0. Instead, you can simply print out each digit in reverse. Another thing to note is you shouldn't use `sum` as a variable since it will overwrite the built in `sum` function.

```
parameter = int(input())
while parameter > 0:
    digit = parameter % 10
    print(digit, end='')
    parameter = parameter // 10
print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by printing the output right-justified in a field of the same width as the original number. This doesn't really avoid the fact that string manipulation is required, but at least it allows you to store the number as a number and not a string:

```
from math import ceil, log10

...

digits = ceil(log10(parameter + 1)) or 1

...

print(f'{sum:>0{digits}}')
```